# jQuery Sortable: add visual helper only on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Currently all hidden drop zones are shown when the start event fires. But I want this to happen only when the dragged element is over another element that has that hidden zone. I couldn't find any event that will give the element being below my dragged one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <style>
  body {
   padding: 10px 40px;
  }
  
  #sortable span {
   display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #sortable ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
  }
 
  #sortable ul li {
   padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #sortable ul ul {
   margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  }
  
  #sortable .empy-sortable {
   background: #cfffc9;
   height: 42px;
   border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
   display: none;
  }
  
  .ui-sortable-placeholder {
   background: #b4fcff;
   height: 42px;
   border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  }
  
  .ui-sortable-helper .empy-sortable {
   display: none !important;
  }
  
  i.fa-arrows {
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  }
  
  i.fa-arrows:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .test {
   display: block !important;
   border: 10px solid red !important;
  }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sortable">
  <ul class="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="0" data-id="1">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
   
    <span>Cat 1</span>
    
    <ul class="sortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="1" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 11</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
     
     <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="1" data-id="3">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
      
      <span>Cat 12</span>
      
      <ul class="sortable">
       <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="3" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 121</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
       <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="3" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 122</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
       <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="3" data-id="6"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 123</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
   <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="0" data-id="7">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
    
    <span>Cat 2</span>
    
    <ul class="sortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="7" data-id="8"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 2</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
   <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="0" data-id="9">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
   
    <span>Cat 3</span>
    
    <ul class="sortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="9" data-id="10">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
     
      <span>Cat 31</span>
     
      <ul class="sortable">
       <li class="ui-state-default" data-parent-id="10" data-id="11"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> <span>Cat 331</span><ul class="sortable empy-sortable"></ul></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var $sortable = $('#sortable');
   
   $('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    handle: '.fa-arrows',
    helper: 'clone',
    //tolerance: 'pointer',
    //axis: "y",
    //forceHelperSize: true,
    //toleranceElement : '>span',
    start: function(evt, ui) { 
     var $item = $(ui.item);
     
     $('#sortable .empy-sortable').css('display', 'block');
     
     var id = $item.data('id');
     var parentId = $item.data('parent-id');
         
     //console.log('[moving item with ID '+id+']');
     //console.log('[serching item\'s parent with ID '+parentId+']');
     
     // The only way to search for the parent is from the data attribute
     var $parent = $sortable.find('li[data-id="'+parentId+'"]');
     
     //console.log('[item parent]');
     //console.log($parent);
     
     var $childrenContainer = $parent.find('>.sortable');
     var childrenCount = $childrenContainer.find('>li').length;
     
     //console.log('[children container]');
     //console.log($childrenContainer);    
     //console.log('[item\'s parent has '+childrenCount+' children left]');
     
     // This should be 0 but we use 3 instead; what sorcery is this?
     if (childrenCount == 3) {
      $childrenContainer.addClass('empy-sortable').css('display', 'block');
     }
    },
    stop: function(evt, ui) {
     console.log('[stop event]');
     
     var $item = $(ui.item);
     
     var $parent = $item.parent().parent();
     
     var parentId = $parent.is('li') ? $parent.data('id') : 0;
     
     //console.log('[item\'s new parent]');
     //console.log($parent);
     //console.log('[setting the new data parent attribute with ID '+parentId+']');

     // Set the item's new parent ID
     $item.data('parent-id', parentId);
     
     // This class is present only if the new parent didn't have children before
     $parent.find('>.sortable').removeClass('empy-sortable');
      
     $('#sortable .empy-sortable').css('display', 'none');
    },
    update: function(evt, ui) {
     console.log('[update event]');
    },
    over: function(evt, ui) {
     console.log('[over event]');
     
     console.log($(this), ui);
    },
    change: function(evt, ui) {
     console.log('[change event]');
     
     var $heper = $(ui.helper);    
     
     var $prevChildrenContainer = $heper.prev().find('.empy-sortable');
     var $nextChildrenContainer = $heper.next().find('.empy-sortable');
        
     //console.log('[previous children container]');
     //console.log($prevChildrenContainer);
     //console.log('[next children container]');
     //console.log($nextChildrenContainer);
     
     if ($prevChildrenContainer.length) {
      //$prevChildrenContainer.css('display', 'block');
     }
              
     if ($nextChildrenContainer.length) {
      //$nextChildrenContainer.css('display', 'block');
     }
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code directly in the question, not just link to a fiddle? Also, take an extra 30 seconds and format your code snippet.